# Overriding can't assign mass-protected attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I have fields that should not be accessible for anybody, so I can't just add these fields to attr_accessible. But also I have active admin which should have access to those fields. So far I tried next:

```
controller do
  def update
    org = Organization.find_by_id(params[:id])
    org.subscription.plan_id = params[:organization][:subscription_attributes][:plan_id]
    org.subscription.expires_at = params[:organization][:subscription_attributes][:expires_at]
    org.save
    super
  end
end
```

But `super` still call update attributes on all params, not just ones that were changed. How can I exclude fields to be updated in super?

Comment: I am not sure what you exactly want to do but if you want to remove specific attributes from params hash then you can delete the key value pair in has using `delete`. So if you want to delete `plan_id` from params, you could do it by `params[:organization][:subscription_attributes].delete(:plan_id)`.

Comment: I could, but in case if something go wrong(validation fails), i won't have access to these data anymore untill new refresh

Comment: Right.. But if you save them in some variable and then put them back in failing condition. e.g. `plan_id = params[:organization][:subscription_attributes].delete(:plan_id)` and then merge it back in failing condition like `params[:organization][:subscription_attributes][:plan_id] = plan_id`

Comment: This won't work aswell, because when you call super, method stores params into variable. But when i try to overwrite it with needed params, i still can't catch it

Comment: I am not sure then what do you have in super!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the strong_parameters gem for rails 3.

It has always been quite a discusion whether the validation must be ran at Model or Controller level.

By using strong parameters you can easily set your permitted parameters in a controller action:

```
params.permit(:name, {:emails => []}, :friends => [ :name, { :family => [ :name ], :hobbies => [] }])
```

Also in Rails 4 this will become the default.

Answer (score 0):

According to sources of active admin, i called a block on super method, and passes required params there. 
result code looks like this

```
def update
      plan_id = params[:organization][:subscription_attributes].delete(:plan_id)
      expires_at = params[:organization][:subscription_attributes].delete(:expires_at)
      update! do
          resource.subscription.plan_id = plan_id
          resource.subscription.expires_at  = expires_at
          resource.subscription.save if resource.valid?
      end
    end
```